# Setting up SQUID PROXY NCSA authentication on a windows machine

Tags: windows-server-2003, authentication, squid

I have Squid Proxy installed on a windows machine. I want the users to authenticate themeselves when ever they access the net, i.e: An html page is displayed prompting for a username and password before continuing. From my research I have found plenty help setting it up on a Linux machine, but nothing on a windows machine.

My config looks like such:

```
auth_param basic program c:/squid/libexec/ncsa_auth c:/squid/etc/passwd
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Squid proxy-caching web server
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
auth_param basic casesensitive off

acl ncsa_users proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow ncsa_users
```

This doesnt do anything. All users still get access to the net without a prompt. I checked the folders I'm pointing to for my basic auth program(c:/squid/libexec/ncsa_auth and c:/squid/etc/passwd) and they are both empty. I'm guessing something is supposed to be in there but I dont know what. Could someone please shed some light on the matter?